# How to see login history of an user in exchange 2010

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, exchange, exchange-2010

How to see login history of an user in exchange 2010? We tried with Get-LogonStatistics but it only shows the last login time, same goes for Get-MailboxStatistics.

I see some data in IIS logs but I'm not sure if user logged in or not.

Comment: Are you trying to track logins via Outlook or OWA?

Answer (score 0):

You do it outside of Exchange itself to get Outlook and OWA.

You'll set the local security policy on the Exchange server(s) Audit Policies.

Set "Audit Account Logon Events" and "Audit Logon Events" as success/failure.

Then you can look in the Security log in eventvwr (or query it with other tools or 3rd party programs) for user's accessing their mailboxes or attempting to.